# how to display the date after a selection on a button

Tags: angular, typescript

When I select a date via a button, I don't see the value selected.
I don't understand why ?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group">

    <div class="input-group">

      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"

           name="dp" [(ngModel)]="myDate" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">

      <div class="input-group-append">

        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>

<h1>My date => {{myDate }} </h1>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',

  templateUrl: './app.component.html',

  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'appBootstrap';

  model;
  myDate;


  constructor() {}
}
```

Here is my code on [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zqs6po?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I would really like to solve this problem, many thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the same template variable `#d` is pointing to two different instances of `NgbDatepicker` in your component.

I have made the required corrections in the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cbxrlc?file=src/app/app.component.html) project to reflect the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this- When the user changes the date it automatically changes the input's value, also use dateChanged method to do whatever you want with that

TS:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)" [matDatepicker]="picker"
          placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      <h1>The Date: {{getDateString()}}</h1>
    </div>
  `
})
export class DatePickerComponent {

  constructor() {}

  date: Date;
  dateChanged(event) { this.date = event.value }
  getDateString() { return this.date && this.date.toDateString() }
}
```

Don't forget on your module file:

```
import { MatDatepickerModule } from "@angular/material"
import { DatePickerComponent } from './components/date-picker/date-picker.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DatePickerComponent],
  imports: [MatDatepickerModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}
  ]
})
```